# Can we retrieve steps from command line?

Tags: command-line

Actually I was running a executing a tool from command line. For this I had executed some steps on command prompt.

But mistakenly machine was restarted and I lost all the steps that I performed on cmd.

There were at least 12-15 steps I executed before restarting the machine.

Is there a way so that I can retrieve the steps that I performed on command prompt?

Comment: history     should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

press UP arrow of your keyboard to get the last command you executed (press up arrow 2 times to get command before last command etc;)

Comment: So you're saying command prompt history in Windows will work across a system reboot?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using some version of Windows? AFAIK command prompt (DOSKey) history is not saved to disk and thus cannot be retrieved even if you close and reopen the window, much less reboot the PC.

Answer (score 0):

[LastActivityView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_activity_view.html) from NirSoft might tell you what EXEs were run, and it might give you some other hints. It won't tell you what the command line parameters were though.

[image: screenshot of LastActivityView]

Comment: Doesn't even seem as if he's talking about command-line params though. By "12-15 steps" it seems he means that he executed those many separate commands in a command prompt window, and now hopes to retrieve them after a system restart.